# Qual a melhor tradução para "scroll up", "scroll down", "zoom in" e "zoom out"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, expressões-idiomáticas

Qual a melhor tradução para "scroll up", "scroll down", "zoom in" e "zoom out"?

Aqui no Brasil, geralmente, dizemos:

Tradução:

1. scroll up = rolar para cima;
2. scroll down = rolar para baixo;
3. zoom in = dar um zoom;
4. zoom out = diminuir o zoom.

Expressões usadas em um contexto:

1. Você precisa rolar a tela para cima, por favor;
2. Rola a figura um pouco para baixo, por favor;
3. Para visualizar o objeto você precisa dar um zoom na foto;
4. Para visualizar a imagem toda diminua o zoom.

O que vocês acham? É isso mesmo? E em Portugal e outros países falantes do português como seria?

Comment: Uma sugestão: *zoom in* = *aproximar* ou *aumentar*, e *zoom out* = *desaproximar* ou *diminuir*. Baseado no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/zoom).

Comment: Acho bom o aumentar/diminuir. dar um zoom é muito feio. :)

Comment: Você tem razão, boa sugestão.  Mas a mania de estrangeirismo no Brasil é muito comum. Daí a gente acaba dizendo "zoom" mesmo. rsrs

Comment: @DenisCaixeta, uma opção que já ouvi muito é *ampliar*.

Comment: Tambem esse rolar é engraçado para scroll. Mas se ve: rolar para cima e para baixo.

Comment: Mais referências:  https://www.wordreference.com/enpt/scroll%20up https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/scroll%20up  https://pt.pons.com/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-portugu%C3%AAs/scroll  https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-traducao-de-scroll-down/13816  https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/zoom%20out  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles-portugues/zoom-in-out

Comment: Seria ótimo alguém se dispor a montar uma resposta a partir dos comentários. :-)